# How do I get long command lines to wrap to the next line?

Tags: command-line, bash

Something I have noticed in Ubuntu for a long time that has been frustrating to me is when I am typing a command at the command line that gets longer (wider) than the terminal width, instead of wrapping to a new line, it goes back to column 1 on the same line and starts over-writing the beginning of my command line. (It doesn't actually overwrite the actual command, but visually, it is overwriting the text that was displayed).

It's hard to explain without seeing it, but let's say my terminal was 20 characters wide (Mine is more like 120 characters - but for the sake of an example), and I want to echo the English alphabet.  What I type is this:

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

But what my terminal looks like before I hit the  key is:

```
pqrstuvwxyzghijklmno
```

When I hit enter, it echos

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

so I know the command was received properly.  It just wrapped my typing after the "o" and started over on the same line.

What I would expect to happen, if I typed this command in on a terminal that was only 20 characters wide would be this:

```
echo abcdefghijklmno
pqrstuvwxyz
```

Background: I am using bash as my shell, and I have this line in my ~/.bashrc:

```
set -o vi
```

to be able to navigate the command line with VI commands.  I am currently using Ubuntu 10.10 server, and connecting to the server with Putty.

In any other environment I have worked in, if I type a long command line, it will add a new line underneath the line I am working on when my command gets longer than the terminal width and when I keep typing I can see my command on 2 different lines.  But for as long as I can remember using Ubuntu, my long commands only occupy 1 line.

This also happens when I am going back to previous commands in the history (I hit Esc, then 'K' to go back to previous commands) - when I get to a previous command that was longer than the terminal width, the command line gets mangled and I cannot tell where I am at in the command.

The only work-around I have found to see the entire long command is to hit "Esc-V", which opens up the current command in a VI editor.

I don't think I have anything odd in my .bashrc file.  I commented out the "set -o vi" line, and I still had the problem.

I downloaded a fresh copy of Putty and didn't make any changes to the configuration - I just typed in my host name to connect, and I still have the problem, so I don't think it's anything with Putty (unless I need to make some config changes)

Has anyone else had this problem, and can anyone think of how to fix it?

**Edit**

It was my .bashrc file.  I've copied the same profile from machine to machine, and I used special characters in my $PS1 that are somehow throwing it off.  I'm now sticking with the standard bash variables for my $PS1.

Thanks to @ændrük for the tip on the .bashrc!

**...End Edit...**

Comment: Just to be sure the issue isn't caused by your .bashrc file, I'd recommend temporarily replacing it with a copy of `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. Keep in mind that you'll need to reconnect for the changes to take effect, and be sure to keep a backup of your own .bashrc.

Comment: Which terminal application are you using ? The behavior you are describing is not usual, certainly not a default.

Comment: In shells that I've worked in (and in Cisco CLI) you can also type Ctrl-L to redisplay the line you are typing, even if it's offscreen.  In your situation, that may still produce the broken output you're talking about, but I'd be curious.

Comment: Feel free to create an "answer" explaining the solution and mark it as accepted. It can seem a little silly, but having a proper answer helps keep the site organized and might more effectively guide others who have similar problems in the future.

Comment: As per [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/619127/171296), use ```tput smam```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Make sure all non-printable bytes in your PS1 are contained within `\[ \]`. Otherwise, bash will count them in the length of the prompt. It uses the length of the prompt to determine when to wrap the line.

For example, here bash counts the prompt as 19 columns wide, while the prompt displayed by the terminal is only 10 columns wide (`My prompt` written in cyan, and `>` written in default color):

```
PS1='\e[36mMy prompt\e[0m>'         # bash count: 19, actual: 10
```

while here it only counts the prompt as 10 columns wide because it ignores the bytes between the special `\[` and `\]` escapes:

```
PS1='\[\e[36m\]My prompt\[\e[0m\]>' # bash count: 10, actual: 10
```

For good practice though, use `tput` to generate the terminal escapes rather than hard coding them:

```
cyan=$(tput setaf 6) # \e[36m
reset=$(tput sgr0)   # \e[0m
PS1='\[$cyan\]My prompt\[$reset\]>'
```

For more information see the following resources

bash prompt: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

tput: https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php

Comment: That's a great explanation of the problem that the accepted answer doesn't provide

Comment: In the last line of code `PS1='...'` : why don't single quotes   prevent `$cyan` and `$reset` from substitution?

Comment: @andrybak, they do prevent `$cyan` and `$reset` from being substituted, but `PS1` is evaluated every time the prompt is printed. You can see this by trying `PS1='$var> '` and then give `var` various values and see how the prompt change. Then try `PS1="$var> "`  and notice that the prompt remains static; `$var` got expanded during assignment, not every time `PS1` is evaluated.

Comment: This is amazing.  Thanks so much for posting this!  It makes escaping the square brackets much easier and more readable.

Comment: How I do make this work `PS1=${PS1}"\e]2;$@\a"` . I tried `PS1=${PS1}"\[\e]2;\]$@\[\a\]"`

Comment: @RamanaReddy Don't set the title from PS1. If you want to change the title everytime the prompt changes, use PROMPT_COMMAND, however since you use $@ in there, it suggests you want to set it on demand, so use a function like this: `set_title() { printf '\e]2;%s\a' "$1"; }` And to use it: `set_title "This is TITLE"`.

Comment: Would give +10 upvotes if I can. Great explanation and finally I got how the thing was parsed.

Comment: Fantastic answer!! I also used [.bashrc PS1 Generator](http://bashrcgenerator.com/) to help me solve my problem. Just carefully remove the extra unnecessary `\[$(tput sgr0)\]` bits that it adds after every part that you add.

Comment: This could be better, but I used the following to get a leg up on debugging a complex prompt composed from multiple functions/variables: `printf "%q\n" "${PS1//\\/}"`

Comment: This doens't seem to work for `vi-ins-mode-string` and `vi-cmd-mode-string`... The square brackets are just added to the prompt?

Comment: Okay, so for the vi string, the beginning escape sequence is `\1` and the ending is `\2` instead of `\[` and `\]`. Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#index-vi_002dcmd_002dmode_002dstring

Comment: @winklerrr the `\[` and `\]` in PS1 actually get translated to `\1` and `\2` before it's handed to readline, so it's actually the same, just that when you're dealing with readline directly, you need to use its own `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: @geirha yeah that was the case because I have those settings in my `input.rc`

Answer (score 60):

I guess you have configured your `PS1` with colors, right?

Just make sure you have `\[` inside your `PS1` quote preceding your color set

For example:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;32m\u@\w/:\[\e[m '
```

Comment: My PS1 was `export PS1='^[[96m'$(hostname)'<^[[92m${PWD}^[[96m>^[[97m '` - I've been using that one for a long time - it's KSH compatible...

Comment: Wow.  I've been using terminal prompts since forever and never had this problem before.  Would have never figured that out.  Thanks.

Comment: using \\[ while using simple quotes yields an unintended slash. also, there should be used \] in the end of the magical chars, as noted in the best-voted answer

Comment: -1 Doesn't work. You need to *wrap* the non-printing section with `\[` at the start and `\]` at the end.

Comment: @igorsantos07 The double-backslash in `\\[` was a typo caused by an edit. I've fixed it.

Comment: Doesn't work. The other answer explains the real solution. @BrianH you should select the other answer as the real answer of the question. This one creates more problems than it fixes.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue, and finally found a simple solution.

Add following line in your `.bashrc` file:

```
COLUMNS=250
```

Then type `source ~/.bashrc` to get the desired effect.

Comment: In some cases, such as narrow terminator subdivisions, the problem is not in the promt color characters but just in a wrong COLUMNS value. This answer took me out of a very bothering hole!

Comment: Logging off is unnecessary.  Do `source .bashrc`. Your prompt will update immediately

Comment: I found that since I didn't have shopt `setwinsize` set for my bash, so it wasn't updating COLUMNS right, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167911/8337

Comment: I did `export COLUMNS=250` followed by `export TERM=xterm` and it was happy.

Answer (score 7):

A simple thing to do would be to add the following line before setting the PS1:

```
stty columns 1000
```

For example,

```
stty columns 1000
PS1='\[\e[0;32m\u@\w/:[\e[m '
```

however this does affect other unix commands like ls and man.

Comment: That works in OSX.

Comment: This also affects vim badly. Please don't use this.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with a custom coloured prompt, even though I contained colour codes within `\[` and `\]` delimiters. It turns out that [bash has problems echoing colours from inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592077/bash-prompt-and-echoing-colors-inside-a-function). I ended up just using variables for my prompt, and though my .bashrc is a little less elegant, everything works nicely now.

Comment: If anyone's still reading this, it is actually possible to escape colors in a function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43462720/4518341) on the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when connected in tmux. The problem was that I had an `ipython` session in the background (`ctrl + z`) and that somehow broke line wrapping. As soon as I terminated it (`fg`, `ctrl+d+d`) my terminal started working properly

So check for any stopped interactive prompts.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had the same issue with a slight *twist* on it and I thought I would share my solution too, just to add my little nuance :D

My initial PS1 was

```
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$"
```

The problem I had was that I was trying to change my terminal **title** as well as the command prompt. The way I did this was by adding `\[\033]0;\]Title\a` to the **PS1** variable.

So now my PS1 was:

```
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$\[\033]0;\]Title\a"
```

This messed up the line wrapping for me. I finally figured out that bash doesn't seem to like having `\a` at the end. To circumvent this, I put the title in a variable, which seemed to fix it.

```
TITLE="\033]0;Title\a"
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$\[$TITLE\]"
```

Answer (score 0):

`\[` and `\]` didn't work for me. I guess there was something different about how I was generating the prompt (from an external program), or because my prompt was "dynamic".

After [reading this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053) I found that you can actually escape the color codes with the `0x01` and `0x02` bytes.

e.g. I'm using a special version of [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nasc/chalk#chalkwrapper) and I wrap the colors using this:

```js
const Chalk = require('@nasc/chalk');

const chalk = new Chalk.constructor({
  wrapper: {
    pre: '\1',
    post: '\2',
  }
});
```