# How do I keep terminal line from overwriting itself?

Tags: command-line

In a terminal window any smaller than fullscreen, if I type in a long command it starts overwriting the current line I'm on. If I type an additional line's worth, it finally moves to the next line. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is what happens visually:

[image: terminal screenshot]

**Edit**: These are my prompt settings:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\033[1m`__git_ps1`\033[0m\$ '
TERM=xterm
```

`.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\033[1m`__git_ps1`\033[0m\$ '
fi

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For some reason the terminal size is mis-reporting. It should change when you resize the terminal.

Try this in your .bashrc command file:

```
# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Comment: It looks like this was already in my .bashrc file. Running `shopt` shows that checkwinsize is on.

Comment: Hmm, what are the values of LINES and COLUMNS when the text is messed up?

Comment: LINES is 24, COLUMNS is 80. Resizing the window does change these values, but the text is still messed up.

Comment: Ah. OK, I suspect the setting for the PROMPT now. Can you post the values of `PS1` and `TERM`. In fact, post the line defining PS1 in `.bashrc`

Comment: I updated the question with these answers.

Comment: OK, so what happens if you set PS1 to something rather simpler? Say something like `\u@\h: \w\a\ ` or just `zzzzzzzzzzzzz> ` (just to keep it long).

Comment: That does the trick! It looks like `\033[1m\`__git_ps1\`\033[0m` was causing it. By taking out the formatting (`\033[1m` and `\033]0m`) I can keep the git branch in there and the text will wrap fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, glad we fixed it between us.

Comment: It was driving me crazy, thanks for the answer

Comment: I had the `PS1` set to `\$ ` via `PS1='\$ '` in the `~/.bashrc`. Turns out the use of single quotes confuses the backslash-escaped dollar sign in the PS1 assignment, readjusted to double-quotes `PS1="\$ "` - et voilà. Hope helps someone, quite a lot of frustration on my part to finally figure that one out.

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24358/how-do-i-get-long-command-lines-to-wrap-to-the-next-line). The answer with the most votes solved it for me.

To sum it up I had to wrap my formats in `\[ \]`
`export PS1='\[\033[1;32m\]$(whoami)@$(hostname): \[\033[0;37m\]$(pwd)$ \[\033[0m\]'`

Answer (score 1):

For those using PuTTY terminal (v0.67) and terminal size is not updated correctly:

1. You can right click on the window's left hand icon, then select **Change Settings...**.
2. Within **PuTTY Reconfiguration**, from left hand sidebar, click on **Window** > **Set the size of the window** > **Columns**.
3. Update the **Columns** value manually. I changed mine to 255 and that stopped the terminal overwriting on its own line (when I type).

[image: menu screenshot]

[image: settings screenshot]

Comment: Note that Windows applications are technically off-topic here, but this is fine for the sake of people SSH-ing into Ubuntu installs.