# My terminal line keeps overwriting itself

Tags: command-line

So whenever I try to type a command and it gets too long. The command just overwrites itself. I have tried multiple things like:

- `shopt`
- `shopt -s checkwinsize`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- `eval $(resize)`
- `if [ $(tty) == '/dev/ttyS0' ]; then trap resize DEBUG; fi`

and I have enclosed my color command in the `~/.bashrc` file in `[]` but still no luck.
Any help would be appriciated.

---

I found the source of the problem: The issue lies with my `PS1` line on my `~/.bashrc` file.

```
 export PS1="[\e[0;32m[\u@\h \W]\$ "
```

is what I have in my file currently.

Comment: check your `PS1` and make sure colors are properly escaped.  see https://askubuntu.com/a/24416/669043

Comment: just tried it with no colors but no luck

Comment: But I know where the problem is. But I want to change the color of the whole line but when I do. The command does not wrap.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this answer on "How do I get long command lines to wrap to the next line?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/24422/301745), you have a problem in your PS1:

```
export PS1="[\e[0;32m[\u@\h \W]\$ "
```

So change `\e[0;32m` to `\[\e[0;32m\]`:

```
export PS1="\[\e[0;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$ "
```

Also, you'll probably want to <strike>remove that zero in `\e[0;32m` since it does nothing, and</strike>* reset the color at the end of the prompt with `\e[m`:

```
export PS1="\[\e[0;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] "
```

***Correction** from [Egmont](https://askubuntu.com/users/398785/egmont)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970381/my-terminal-line-keeps-overwriting-itself/970414#comment1554599_970414):

> That `0` resets the attributes, it makes a difference if the previously executed command didn't clean up after itself, e.g. left a nondefault background color, bold/italic/etc. attribute. In that case it's reverted. Under "normal" circumstances it doesn't do anything, but is harmless.

Comment: That `0` resets the attributes, it makes a difference if the previously executed command didn't clean up after itself, e.g. left a nondefault background color, bold/italic/etc. attribute. In that case it's reverted. Under "normal" circumstances it doesn't do anything, but is harmless.

Comment: Just tried that but now about a quarter the way on the second line it rewrites on the second line

Comment: @IvanJones It works perfectly for me. Are you sure you have it set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, I went symbol by symbol. Anyways I just decided to give up. I deleted the commands for the colors.

Comment: @egmont Thanks! I added that to the answer. I saw your comment when you posted it but forgot to do anything about it at the time, except upvote.