# Terminal line overwritten in a screen session

Tags: command-line, bash, gnu-screen

I have this problem while working on a screen session that the terminal line gets overwritten. If I detach from the screen session then I don't run into this problem.

Here are some of the configurations that I believe might help:

```
[~]$cat ~/.screenrc
altscreen on
defscrollback 15000
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
termcapinfo *  vb=:
vbell off

[~]$screen --version
Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06

[~]$echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

[~]$echo $COLUMNS
234

[~]$echo $TERM
screen

[~]$echo $PS1
\[\e[1;32m\][\w]\$\[\e[0m\]
```

I have `shopt -s checkwinsize` in my `.bashrc`. I've gone through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24358/how-do-i-get-long-command-lines-to-wrap-to-the-next-line?newreg=66c677c90eb24cdebb355d0237f17968) but I already have most of what is suggested (enclosing colored PS1 in `[` and `]` and having `COLUMNS` set to a reasonably large value). Is there anything else that I need to set as part of my environment to fix this? The one obvious difference I see is that `TERM` is set to `xterm` when I detach from a screen session.

Illustrations that I hope might help explain my problem:

Initial:

[image: Before overwrite]

After overwrite:

[image: After overwrite]

On detaching from screen:

[image: On detaching from screen]

Comment: Could you describe the problem you're facing?

Comment: @egmont "I have this problem while working on a screen session that the terminal line gets overwritten. If I detach from the screen session then I don't run into this problem." This is the problem. Please do tell if the issue isn't still clear.

Comment: Well, repeating the same words isn't quite what I expected. "The terminal line gets overwritten" – what do you mean by this? Do you mean the "terminal line" as /dev/pts/0 or something similar, analogous to let's say a phone line? Or by "terminal line" do you mean a physical row of the display containing unexpected things? Or do you mean the value of $TERM, is that the problem? Or what else? What do you _exactly_ do inside screen, what commands do you issue, what is the exact output that you have a problem with, what output would you expect to see instead? (Please edit the post to answer these)

Comment: On a side note, I can't help notice that you're using an ancient version of `screen`, all currently supported Ubuntu releases ship a newer one.

Comment: @egmont I've added illustrations to explain my problem. And by terminal line, I'm referring to the bash terminal (`/dev/pts/4`)